# Asymptotic dimension of solvable group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated solvable group and $\frac {N_k} {N_{k-1}}$ are finitely generated for all $k$, where $N_k$ is an element of the subnormal series. I am to prove that the asymptomatic dimension of $G$ is finite. A result of Bell and Dranishnikov states that $asdim G \leq (asdim X = 1)(\alpha + 1) - 1$, where $G$ is a finitely generated group that acts on a metric space $X$ by isometries and $asdim Stab_R(x_0)\leq \alpha$ for every $R > 0$. $x_0 \in X$ and $Stab_R(x) = \{ g \in G | d(x,gx)\leq R\}$. It seems natural that we first make $G$ act on $\frac{G} {N_r}$, where $N_r$ is the last group in the subnormal series. Since each $\frac {N_k} {N_{k-1}}$ is finitely generated, it seems that we need to make $\frac {N_k} {N_{k-1}}$ act on something, but I cannot think of anything on which it can act isometrically.

Comment: This quotient is a finitely generated abelian group. Can you think of a space where such group acts isometrically, properly and cocompactly?

Comment: Anything quasi isometric to it?

Comment: This would be false. How about working out the case of cyclic groups?

Comment: Are you hinting towards the Svarc Milnor Theorem? $N_k$ acts on $\frac {N_k}{N_{k-1}}$, but the obvious actions like left multiplication and conjugation are not properly discontinuous. Maybe one requires the fact that the quotient is abelian to construct such a function. If $N_k$ is finitely generated, the proof will be done.

Comment: Are you telling me that you cannot think of any geodesic metric space on which ${\mathbb Z}$ acts isometrically, properly discontinuously and cocompactly?

Comment: Obviously, translation on real numbers; sorry, my response was to your previous comment.

Comment: OK, now you are ready to answer your own question "it seems that we need to make $N_k/_{−1}$  act on something, but I cannot think of anything on which it can act isometrically", taking into account that this quotient group is finitely generated abelian.